# Cannot properly get the value of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list and a javascript function which disables other fields when a certain value from the dropdown list is selected.

Javascript Code

```
function maritalStatusChange()
    {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("maritalstatus").value;

        if(dropdown == 'Single')
        {
            document.getElementById("spousefld").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("spouse_occupation").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("address3").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("children_no").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("spousefld").value = "";
            document.getElementById("spouse_occupation").value = "";
            document.getElementById("address3").value = "";
            document.getElementById("children_no").value= "None";
                }
        if(dropdown == 'Married')
        {
            document.getElementById("spousefld").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("spouse_occupation").disabled= false;
            document.getElementById("address3").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("children_no").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("maritalstatus").value= 'Married';
                }
        if(dropdown == 'Separated')
        {
            document.getElementById("spousefld").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("spouse_occupation").disabled= false;
            document.getElementById("address3").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("children_no").disabled = false;
        }
        if(dropdown == 'Widowed')
        {
            document.getElementById("spousefld").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("spouse_occupation").disabled= false;
            document.getElementById("address3").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("children_no").disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML code of the dropdown list and where I call the javascript function.

```
<select name="maritalstatus" id="maritalstatus" onchange="maritalStatusChange();">
                                <option>---------------</option>
                                <option value='Single'>Single</option>
                                <option value='Married'>Married</option>
                                <option value='Separated'>Separated</option>
                                <option value='Widowed'>Widowed</option>
                                </select><font color="red">*</font>
```

Right now, the only thing that works is when I select the "Single" option however, it does not seem to get proper selected value for the rest of the options. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `val()` instead of `value` in line 3 - `var dropdown = document.getElementById("maritalstatus").val();`

Comment: val() is a jquery method. If he doesn't have jquery installed it won't work

Comment: That's a jQuery function. Not native Javascript!

Comment: I changed the code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ya its jquery method. Works if your using jQuery library.

Comment: If you have `alert(dropdown);` what value you see?

Comment: When I alert the dropdown, it properly shows what I have selected in the dropdown. But whenever I try adding the values to my database, only the "Single" option can be added.

Comment: @JosephTadioan - Hey lots of working solution are given as answer. Click this try my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698252/cannot-properly-get-the-value-of-a-dropdown/9698425#9698425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

`var dropdown =  document.getElementById("maritalstatus").options[document.getElementById("maritalstatus").selectedIndex].value;`

Answer (score 0):

You should try "selectedIndex":

```
    document.getElementById("maritalstatus").selectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine. You can see it at: http://jsfiddle.net/WmHCs/

What is the actual error? Maybe some other part of the code?

Comment: it does not really show an error, it just doesn't properly add the selected value to my db. It only works whenever the selected value is "Single", but fails at any other value.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
var eve = document.getElementById("maritalstatus");
var data = eve.options[eve.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotas in HTML. Switch them to double quotas. All values for `options` are assigned with those single quotas. This is what you are actually comparing: `("'Single'"=="Single") => false`.

**EDIT**

If this code is supposed to add the selection in your `db`, check `if`-blocks other than `Single`. In case `Single` you set some values, but other blocks are making some disablings only.

Comment: I swithced it to double quotes but it produced the same results.

Comment: @JosephTadioan In one of your comments was this: "it just doesn't properly add the selected value to my db." Seems that the posted code is OK. Please post the part of the code where you add the value to `db`. Or should it be done in this code, but you've forgotten to do it?

Comment: I could correctly add to my db ONLY when the selected option is "Single" which is kinda weird.

Comment: @JosephTadioan We'll see, if you just post the code which does this adding.

Comment: Got it to work. There has been a conflict with my condition to add to the db with other parts of the javascript. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get value from element by id and then alert the value.

Create a function and call it on change. it works in many of values dynamically generated, no limitaion of entries in dropdown.

```
<select name="maritalstatus" id="maritalstatus" onchange="maritalStatusChange();">

function maritalStatusChange()
 {
   var getValue = document.getElementById("maritalstatus").value;
   alert(getValue);
 }
```